# On try to access product in admin I get "Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Uploader_Block_Multiple' not found in ../Block/Media/Uploader.php on line 39"

Tags: product, admin, migration

I pulled whole site from a git repo. Now I am getting this message when I try to access product in admin:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Uploader_Block_Multiple' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/libraccio/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Media/Uploader.php on line 39
```

Everything else in admin seems to work fine. Displays fine, menus appear fine and other functionalities. What is causing this?

Edited: I copied over whole directory `app/code/core/Mage/Uploader` from Magento 1.9.3 per Rafael's advice and now I get this message when I try to get to admin product page:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getConfig() on boolean in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/libraccio/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Helper/Form/Gallery/Content.php:50
```

Again, what can cause this?

Comment: I solved the problem here:
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146219/error-on-product-page-call-to-a-member-function-getconfig-on-boolean-in-mage/146694#146694

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `Mage_Uploader` classes have been introduced with SUPEE-8788 patch or with 1.9.3.X versions.

As you said you pulled the whole site from a GIT repo, my guess is that **the `app/code/core/Mage/Uploader` directory has not been committed to that repo when the website has been patched / upgraded.**

A hacky fix would be to download the 1.9.3 Magento files and copy the `app/code/core/Mage/Uploader` directory from the fresh files to your repo

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic on the Magento website

Comment: I tried to apply the patch that you mentioned, with the same result. I also tried to copy over the files from v 1.9.3 with same result. Noting helped.

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic well that second error with `getConfig()` means the `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Helper/Form/Gallery/Content.php` has not been updated either. I think your upgrade failed and you should try a manual upgrade with all the 1.9.3 files

Comment: This is a no. I can't change every Magento file just to fix a bug.

Comment: Running the patch mentioned in this answer and together with this bug fix solved the problem:
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146219/error-on-product-page-call-to-a-member-function-getconfig-on-boolean-in-mage