# Error on Product page: Call to a member function getConfig() on boolean in Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Helper/Form/Gallery/Content.php:50

Tags: product, admin

This errors prevents me from going to admin product page at all:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getConfig() on boolean in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/libraccio/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Helper/Form/Gallery/Content.php:50
```

This is what I tried:

1. Overwriting the `app/code/core` files from a fresh `Magento 1.9.2` installation
2. Running everything on a different server, with `PHP 5`, instead of `PHP 7`

What else can cause this error to happen?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27011068/unable-to-open-product-from-magento-backend-it-is-showing-fatal-error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the most probable correct answer. There are some files missing (I saw in logs) that are incorrectly given in .gitignore ("media" entry -  instead of "/media" - in .gitignore in conjunction with git case ignore results in loss of a lot of directories and files).

Comment: I had an issue like this, and in my case it was the `app/code/core/Mage/Uploader` folder that was missing

Answer (score 2):

I reckon you did not upgrade your Magento store properly.

In 1.9.3 there is no such call to `getConfig()` in this file you can find the 1.9.3 file here: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Helper/Form/Gallery/Content.php

So I suggest you:

- Backup your files
- Download a fresh 1.9.3 install
- Copy the 1.9.3 files over your website files
- Try again

Comment: Sorry, this is a big mistake by me. The version of the Magento is actually 1.9.2. I will edit the question.

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic did you apply SUPEE-8788 ?

Comment: I have just applied it and it worked! But there is not any style and almost everything is missing. There is no menu items on the left hand side. There are just radio boxes for choosing the images.

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic do you have any error in the console or in the logs ?

Comment: This is the most probable correct answer. There are some files missing (I saw in logs) that are incorrectly given in .gitignore ("media" entry in .gitignore in conjunction with git case ignore results in lose of a lot of directories)

Answer (score 0):

We need to remove the media in .gitignore so that the media core files will be shown to commit. Once after committing all the files for the first time we can add them back to .gitignore. It will work fine.